# Jade: How do I create a layout or templates?

Tags: html, css, pug, haml

I'm designing few pages in HTML using Jade. I've problem while compiling common areas of the pages. Header, Footer, Navs etc. How do I create a template files and include it the files or how do I create a layout to use in all files?

I'm very new to Jade and couldn't find something related to creating a layout or templates to use.

In PHP for example you create header.php, footer.php and nav.php and include those in the files. One change affects all the other files. How to accomplish something like that in Jade?

P.S. I'm not using Node.js or Express.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the extends function in jade, that will allow you to extend the different files. Like include in php.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/